# How to plot a pandas multiindex dataFrame with all xticks

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, pandas

I have a pandas dataFrame like this:

```
                     content
date                        
2013-12-18 12:30:00        1
2013-12-19 10:50:00        1
2013-12-24 11:00:00        0
2014-01-02 11:30:00        1
2014-01-03 11:50:00        0
2013-12-17 16:40:00       10
2013-12-18 10:00:00        0
2013-12-11 10:00:00        0
2013-12-18 11:45:00        0
2013-12-11 14:40:00        4
2010-05-25 13:05:00        0
2013-11-18 14:10:00        0
2013-11-27 11:50:00        3
2013-11-13 10:40:00        0
2013-11-20 10:40:00        1
2008-11-04 14:49:00        1
2013-11-18 10:05:00        0
2013-08-27 11:00:00        0
2013-09-18 16:00:00        0
2013-09-27 11:40:00        0
```

date being the index.
I reduce the values to months using:

```
dataFrame = dataFrame.groupby([lambda x: x.year, lambda x: x.month]).agg([sum])
```

which outputs:

```
         content
             sum
2006 3        66
     4        65
     5        48
     6        87
     7        37
     8        54
     9        73
     10       74
     11       53
     12       45
2007 1        28
     2        40
     3        95
     4        63
     5        56
     6        66
     7        50
     8        49
     9        18
     10       28
```

Now when I plot this dataFrame, I want the x-axis show every month/year as a tick. I have tries setting xticks but it doesn't seem to work. How could this be achieved? This is my current plot using dataFrame.plot():

[image]

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use `set_xtick()` and `set_xticklabels()`:

```
idx = pd.date_range("2013-01-01", periods=1000)
val = np.random.rand(1000)
serie = pd.Series(val, idx)
df = serie.groupby([serie.index.year, serie.index.month]).mean()

ax = df.plot()
ax.set_xticks(range(len(df)))
ax.set_xticklabels(["%s-%02d" % item for item in df.index.tolist()], rotation=90)
```

output:

[image]

Comment: How to set the xticks to the first day of each month?

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39714724/pandas-plot-x-axis-tick-frequency-how-can-i-show-more-ticks/48401584#48401584

Answer (score 0):

You can do it within Pandas plotting function like:

```
df.col.plot.line(
    figsize=(10,8),
    title='Figure Title',
    xlabel='Year, Month',
    xticks=range(len(df)),
    rot=90
)
```

Where:

- `xticks` is the parameter where you set the frequency of the ticks on the abscissa
- `rot` rotates the abscissa labels by 90 degrees

I find this quicker for rapid visualisation.