# Color barchart based on value

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, bar-chart

I am trying to color each bar based on a value, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33476401/color-matplotlib-bar-chart-based-on-value)

I tried a simple code, and it worked:

```
df=pd.DataFrame([95,94,99,90,89,91,92,85], columns=["Value"])
mask1 = df.Value < 90
mask2 = df.Value >= 90
bar=plt.bar( df.index[mask1],df.Value[mask1], color='red')
bar=plt.bar( df.index[mask2],df.Value[mask2], color='blue')
plt.hlines(90,0,7);
```

[image]

The problem is that when I apply to my dataset the order of the columns are changed. The original data is:
         `.        %REALIZADAS
    MÊS
    JANEIRO   96
    FEVEREIRO 86
    MARÇO     94
    ABRIL     96
    MAIO      85
    JUNHO     92
    JULHO     96
    AGOSTO    92
    SETEMBRO  94
    OUTOBRO   94
    NOVEMBRO  97
    DEZEMBRO  94`

And I plotted it using
 `plt.bar(coleta.index, coleta['%REALIZADAS'])
plt.xticks(rotation=90)`
results in this chart:

[image]

And I tried this code:

```
mask1= coleta["%REALIZADAS"]>=90
mask2= coleta["%REALIZADAS"]<90
bar=plt.bar(coleta.index[mask1], coleta['%REALIZADAS'][mask1],    color="blue")
bar=plt.bar(coleta.index[mask2], coleta['%REALIZADAS'][mask2],    color="red")
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.hlines(90, 0,11, color='black')
```

But resulted in this chart:

[image]

How can I keep the order of the columns?

Answer (score 1):

You did not post your dataframe, but I assume that the indeces of your dataframe are not numbers but the name of each Month, which I assume is throwing off the positioning of the column as I did on purpose here:

```
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

df=pd.DataFrame([95,94,99,90,89,91,92,85], columns=["Value"])
df.index = ["a{}".format(i) for i in range(len(df))]  #<--- my fault!

mask1 = df.Value < 90
mask2 = df.Value >= 90

bar=plt.bar( df.index[mask1],df.Value[mask1], color='red')
bar=plt.bar( df.index[mask2],df.Value[mask2], color='blue')
plt.hlines(90,0,7)
```

One possible solution can be this:

```
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

df=pd.DataFrame([95,94,99,90,89,91,92,85], columns=["Value"])

df["colors"] = "red"
df["colors"].mask(df.Value >= 90, "blue", inplace=True)

plt.bar([i for i in range(len(df))], df["Value"], color=df["colors"])
plt.show()
```

I create another column called `colors` and I initialize it to all `red`. Then based on the condition `df.Value >= 90` I set the appropriate cell colors to `blue`.
I pass then this to the bar plot with the `color` argument, and to be sure that the indeces are correct I just create a list with integers from `0` to `len(df)`.

Hope it helps!

Comment: You are wright aboute the names at the index. I edites the question. Your example worked but did not show the names at x-label. How can I do it?

Comment: `plt.xticks(ticks=[i for i in range(len(df))], labels=["a" for i in range(len(df))])`. Obviously replace the labels with what you want